# Profit = Revenue - cost

Tags: mathematical-statistics

if:
Price=$0.50 each.
Cost = $0.10 each.
Monthly overhead = $500. 
How many products I have to produce (per month) to make a profit?

Answer (score 1):

$Profit = 0.5x - 0.1x - 500$

Where $x$ is the number of products produced each month (assuming all are sold).

In order to break even, we need $Profit \geq 0$

$0.5x - 0.1x - 500 \geq 0$

$0.4x \geq 500$

$x \geq \frac{500}{0.4}$

$x \geq 1250 $

So you need to produce at least 1250 units to break even.